# how to escape or sanitise data when its written to a log file, and then cat'd?

Tags: bash, shell, security, logging

I'm developing a chat application, and currently my chat server logs all user-provided text into a logfile (text)

This log file will be periodically viewed in shell/bash, using cat/grep or whatever.

Are there any steps I should take to sanitise this logfile, or escape the user-provided data before its written to the log?

I seem to remember quite a few years ago, awstats had a serious vulnerability because it allowed bash escape codes to be embedded in its logfiles

Sadly I cant find the concrete example Im thinking of.

Comment: In my view, the problem isn't so much how its written to the log file; the problem is how it is process when it is read.

Comment: This might be a first step when reading the logfile: `sed 's/[^[:print:]]//g' logfile`.  This would eliminate, among many other things, the escape character.

Comment: is `cat -v` sufficient for your needs?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The log wont be processed programatically, simply cat'd via ssh, tail'd or grep'd etc. With that in mind, would you say there are no bash escape codes which could cause actual vulnerabilities?

Comment: When you 'simply `cat` via `ssh`', which terminal will you be viewing the data in?  Will it be `cat` or `less` or `more`?  If the data will be going to a terminal, you need to think about whether there are escape codes that could wreak havoc on your terminal.  If you'll always filter the data through a sanitizer (`cat -v` is a possibility, little though I like the options to `cat`), then it may not matter.  But if you ever forget, it might. How long are the lines likely to be?  Will the log data include null bytes? The latter two should be trivial issues, but terminal escape sequences are not.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I guess thats kinda the crux of my question though. Lets assume the worst... I cat a log where a user has intentionally recorded a series of malicious escape codes. What's would be the worst that can come of this?  I can tolerate the terminal display messing up, random colors, bells etc, but are there any escape sequences which could actually cause malicious code to be invoked? (I will use cat -v anyway, but chances are I'll forget at some point, so I want to decide whether I *need* to preprocess these logs to sanitise them for cat without -v)

Comment: Some escape sequences in some terminals can send commands as if they're typed at the keyboard.  That might include fun stuff like `rm -fr / 2>/dev/null &` which won't do you any good.  I'm not sure that's a problem with 'ANSI terminals' and the normal emulations, but it used to be a possibility with some real green-screen hardware terminals (circa 1985, say).  Be extremely cautious.  If you revise the format of the logs, make sure the raw format is recoverable — you might use escape sequences to handle non-printing characters, but make sure the output is 100% unambiguous.